# Output: relational and ternary operator?

Tags: c, output, ternary-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int big,x=3,y=2,z=1,q=4;
big=( x>y ? (x<z ? 20:10 && y>x ? 50:10 ) : (y>z ? 40:10 || x<q ? 30:10));
printf("big =%d",big);
return 0;
}
```

&& is a relational operator so it should return a true or false value i.e 0 or 1, but in this case its not. Please explain whats the logic behind its output?

```
Output: big =10
```

Comment: Please update the question to show us what the output is.

Comment: Who writes code like this?

Comment: this is taken from a portal where one has to predict the output of the following code snippet.. since i wasn't able to figure out i posted it here!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's make your expression a bit more explicit by adding parethesis to show the precedence:

```
((x>y) ?
   ((x<z) ?
     20 : ((10 && (y>x)) ? 50 : 10)
   ) : (
     (y>z)?40:((10 || (x<q))?30:10)
   )
)
```

`x` is greater than `y`, so let's consider

```
((x<z) ?
   20 : ((10 && (y>x)) ? 50 : 10)
)
```

and `x` is not less than `z`, so

```
((10 && (y>x)) ? 50 : 10)
```

`y` is not greater than `x`, so

```
10
```

You can see that the results are not actually of your logical operators.  Because of the complexity involved, you should almost certainly express such an evaluation using `if` statements to break up the logic in a clean way.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about operator precedence (and a distressing lack of parentheses).

The output I get when I run your program is `nbig =10` (with no newline; you should add a `\n` to your format string).

The value assigned to `big` isn't the result of an `&&` or `||` operator. Let's reduce that over-complicated expression, one step at a time. (I've confirmed at each step that the result is unchanged.)

```
big=(x>y?(x<z?20:10 && y>x?50:10) : (y>z?40:10 || x<q?30:10));
```

We know that `x>y` is true, so we can drop the test and the third operand of the corresponding `?:` operator:

```
big=(x<z?20:10 && y>x?50:10);
```

Let's remove the extraneous outer parentheses, add some new around the third operand of the outer `?:` operator, and change the spacing a bit:

```
big = x<z ? 20 : (10 && y>x?50:10);
```

We know that `x<z` is false, so we can drop that and the *second* operand of the outer `?:`:

```
big = (10 && y>x?50:10);
```

Obviously `10` is true, so:

```
big = (y > x ? 50 : 10);
```

And `y > x` is false, so the result is `10` -- which is what I get when I run your program.

You probably assumed that this:

```
 a ? b : c && d ? e : f
```

is equivalent to:

```
 (a ? b : c) && (d ? e : f)
```

but in fact it's equivalent to:

```
 a ? b : ((c && d) ? e : f)
```

because the `&&` operator binds more tightly than the `?:` operator.

In any case, if this is real code, you should definitely add enough parentheses so that a reasonably knowledgeable reader can understand the code without having to consult an operator precedence table. Mixing `&&`, `||`, and `?:` can be particularly confusing. Breaking down the expression into subexpressions, and assigning each one to a temporary variable (so it has a meaningful name) can also be helpful.

The above applies if you're trying to *write* a complex expression. If you're trying to understand something that someone else has written, you pretty much have to parse it yourself. Try doing what I did: incrementally simplify the expression (by removing parts or adding parentheses) in ways that don't change the meaning, confirming at each step that you get the same result. And if it's production code (rather than a quiz, which this appears to be), consider <strike>complaining bitterly</strike> encouraging the author to write clearer code.